Collect and Sum from same ID in google sheet
I am an amateur on Google sheet.
I need help to sum up data with the same multiple ID.
I manage to make dropdown calculation, but somehow its too much work.
I want it summarized for me..
Can anyone help me?
enter image description here
I try to use sumifs
=SUMIFS(C4:C30;E4:E30;L4;D4:D30;K4)

Works OK, but then I have to select data I need all the time.
I want it summarized , I was thinking to use query , but I found it difficult, and fail all the time...

This question is not related to JQuery whatsoever. This is purely Google Sheets, which is not really meant for StackOverflow. Anyhow, the answer provided should suffice.

Preface
So the initial formula is correct:
=SUMIFS(C2:C;D2:D;$K2;E2:E;$L2)

This will sum all "belopp" for each pair of "konto" and "ID".
As described, this formula uses the columns K ("konto") and L ("ID") for the look-ups, which can be tedious since K2 and L2 is changed manually via drop-downs.
Solution
One solution, is to put in a formula in the cell K2:
=UNIQUE(D2:E)

This will extract all unique combinations of "konto" and "ID", and populate the K and L columns. Now, the =SUMIFS(...)-formula can be extended for the entire J-column.
This should yield the sum of "belopp" for all unique combinations of "konto" and "ID". Like so:

To re-iterate
The J2-cell has the =SUMIFS(C2:C;D2:D;$K2;E2:E;$L2)-formula. Drag/Copy it for the entire J-column.
The K2-cell has the formula: =UNIQUE(D2:E).

thank you sooo much! just how I want it. :)

No worries! Would you mind marking this as the answer to your question? Ha det fint! :)

Tack.I am new to this forum, how to do that?
